# Is it possible to disable the retry mechanism in Exim

Tags: email, exim

I have a very simple Exim configuration that's just forwarding all mail to a set of destination addresses.  When immediate delivery to an address fails, the message is added to the queue (and then processed by the retry rules).  I want to change this so that if immediately delivery fails, the message is :blackhole:d.  (It's ok if a bounce is generated instead, as I'll just redirect the bounce to the :blackhole:).

This needs to occur for temporary failures (i.e. 4xx) as well as permanent (i.e. 5xx) ones.

I understand that this means that if delivery can't be done immediately the message will be permanently and irretrievably lost.  In this particular context, that isn't a problem.

Reading over this, it sounds suspiciously like "how can I improve my spamming Exim server".  That really isn't what this is for, and if you can figure out a way I can prove that, I'm happy to do so!

Answer (score 1):

Exim has [extensive configuration](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch32.html) for setting the retry times. In your exim.conf, there will be a retry section near the bottom. The retry configuration is three fields, the email address, the error code causing the failure and a list of timing patterns. These are defined as a group of three numbers: a letter behaviour code, the length of time to apply this rule and an interval to retry. For example:

```
F,2h,15m
```

can be read as "For 2 hours, try of a fixed internal every 15 minutes",

You could try setting an empty retry:

```
begin retry
*    *
```

It's possible that exim gets upset by this. Instead, you could use a single retry of a minute:

```
begin retry
*    *    F,1m,1m
```

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but it's pretty close.

There's also options for changing it for particular email addresses and for different return codes.

Comment: This doesn't work, because (as you said) the retry time is a minute.  That means that there *is* a retry, and the queuerunner has to go through the queue and do the retry and remove the message.  I need to disable retry, not make it short.

Comment: Did you try having an empty retry?

Comment: Yes, Exim ignores an empty retry.  Using 0 for either of the times isn't accepted, either.

Comment: I did wonder if having a short first value with a really long second period, but I suspect Exim might still retry.

Answer (score 1):

Set retry to something absurdly long, cron a script to pull message ids from `exim -bpu` in queue greater than length x, then remove with `exim -Mrm <msgid>`

You can alternatively run exim as a non-queueing daemon with `mua_wrapper = true`. Look at Section 48 "Using Exim as a non-queuing client", it may do what you need.

> When delivery fails, an error message is written to the standard error stream (as well as to Exim’s 
>   log), and Exim exits to the caller with are turn code value 1. The message is expunged from Exim’s 
>   spool files. No bounce messages are ever generated.
>
> No retry data is maintained, and any retry rules are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set `system_filter` option in your exim.conf.
Ater, in your configuration system filter file, create one rule like that:

```
if not first_delivery then
seen finish
endif
```

After first delivery, exim will put message in the queue again but when try to process again, it will discarded.